# Execute code after I open an UILocalNotification

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

How can I detect when an user click on a local notification and open my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this method in your app delegate:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your app will be automatically launched :  you don't have to do anything in your app.